# countable set that contains 1 and pi and has polynomial with coefficients in set s.t. all real roots are in set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, field-theory

Deduce that there is a countable set X that contains the real numbers 1 and pi and has the further property that if P is any non-zero polynomial with coefficients in X, then all real roots of P belong to X.

I have absolutley no idea where to start with this, I have managed the rest of the question but I don't really understand what the question is asking, much less how to do it! Any help is appreciated.

Here is the link to my question (question 5) if you want to read it yourself:
http://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/undergrad/pastpapers/2008/Part_IA/PaperIA_4.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** Recall that adding a single real (algebraic, or transcendental) to $\Bbb Q$ results in a countable field; consider its closure.

Comment: what do you mean by it's closure?

Comment: It's algebraic closure.

Comment: under multiplication?

Comment: I don't see how to use the first part of the question either. It seems to be something like induction but I don't understand about the roots of the polynomials bit.

Comment: @Max:  You are closing under the field operations as well as forming polynomials and finding roots.  Start with $\Bbb Q \cup \pi$.  Now form all the polynomials you can using coefficients in that set and find their real roots.  For example, $\pi x^2 -1$ is such a polynomial with roots $\pm \sqrt \pi$.  Add all these roots in.  Argue that after a countable infinity of these operations, the set is closed under the field operations and finding roots of polynomials.

Comment: @Max: What do you know about field extensions?

Comment: nothing at all, sorry